# Why the LyX getting reset toolbars layout every time it starts?

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

Every time I open Lyx it doesn't restore already opened toolbars (e.g. *version control*, *table of contents*), but instead shows only the default toolbars. How to fix it (make toolbars layout **permanent**)?

Comment: Seems to work fine here, with LyX 2.0.6 in Kubuntu. Which version of LyX for which OS do you have? If no help is found here, try the LyX Users mailing list: http://www.lyx.org/MailingLists

Comment: Does it work if you check the box under Tools > Preferences > Look & Feel > Document Handling > "Restore window layouts and geometries" ?

Answer (score 2):

In order to make the changes to the toolbars persistent, I had to make sure I made the changes on the "Welcome to Lyx!" screen: that is, the screen that comes up when you close all open windows, quit out of Lyx, and then reopen Lyx. Next, I needed to make sure this "Welcome to Lyx!" screen was showing when I opened the file I wanted to work on. This isn't a perfect solution, since if I exit out of this "Welcome to Lyx!" screen and then open a file, the default toolbar layout will be restored.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. The option that you need to change is in the "default.ui" file. For me this was in Lyx system directory -> Contents/Resources/ui. I copied the file to my user directory -> Contents/Resources/ui. I then opened the file with a text editor and modified the Toolbars section as needed. See https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/UserInterface for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Go to lyx preferences/Look&Feel/Document Handling and check the "Restore window layouts and geometries" box.

[image: lyx preferences]

Comment: This does not work if I open a new window from an existing one; it'll have the default toolbars.